# Non-Linear Time Series Book

Tags: time-series, nonlinear

I am looking for a book to study non linear time series for both univariate and multivariate topics. Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not many practical texts on the subject, the one I have is "Nonlinear Time Series: Theory, Methods and Applications with R Examples (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science)", Douc et al Nonlinear TS are very difficult to estimate. I'd day they're impossible to work with unless you deal with a good theory that captures DGP very well, like those in physics and engineering.

One of the co-authors Shumway also wrote a great book on time series, which is available free on his website https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/tsa4.pdf

Comment: Or you can use LSTM and trust the AI...

Comment: Good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

The following book might be helpful:

Elements of Nonlinear Time Series Analysis and Forecasting by Jan G. de Gooijer, published in 2017 by Springer. 
(ISBN 978-3-319-43251-9)